# How to use snapHelper in recyclerview with Custom LayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with a Custom LayoutManager to make the recyclerview curved.I use [TurnLayoutManager](https://github.com/cdflynn/turn-layout-manager) libraryto do that.

Also I use `snapHelper` for my recyclerview to make it easier to select items. 
ex:

```
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(myRecyclerview);
```

**But the problem is when I use `snapHelper`, I can't scroll the recyclerview. How can i fix this?**

This is a picture of what I have

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should implement  RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider for your custom layout manager